# How to pre-render a tile map for redrawing it later?

Tags: java, android, buffer, android-canvas, tile

i'm programming an Android App. I'm using a Canvas and I'm drawing a Tilemap on it by using for-loops and drawing each tile one after another.

I want to increase the performance by render this tilemap (foreground and background individual) once and save it, so that i'm able to draw this whole map without looping threw every single tile.

My Graphics Class looks like this:

```
public class AGraphics implements Graphics {
    Bitmap frameBuffer;
    Canvas canvas;
    Paint paint;
    ...

    public AGraphics(.., Bitmap frameBuffer) {
        this.frameBuffer = frameBuffer;
        this.canvas = new Canvas(frameBuffer);
        this.paint = new Paint();

    }

    ...
    public void drawPixmap(...){
        canvas.drawBitmap(((AndroidPixmap) pixmap).bitmap, ... );
    }

    ...

}
```

My World Class calls the draw Pixmap Function to draw each tile:

```
public class World {
    ...
    public void drawForeground (float posX, float posY){
        // get Graphics ...
        for (int y = 0; y < map.height; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x <map.width; x ++) {
                // calculate Positions
                g.draw(tileset, (int)posX, (int)posY, srcX, srcY, tilesize, tilesize);
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Now i'm looking for a way to save the Canvas and redraw it every GameLoop at different Positions to increase the Performance.

Any ideas or best practices? If u need some more Information pls ask!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a bitmap (one or as many as you need) using `Bitmap.createBitmap`
Create a canvas on that bitmap using `Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap)`
Draw into the canvas

in `onDraw`, draw the ready bitmaps into the output canvas using `canvas.drawBitmap`

Comment: Unfortunately now I got troubles with the memory. I will try it with smaller tiles so that the total image size is smaller. Then i can strech it, that it fits in my canvas. (I used 128x128px per Tile and got a map size something about 120x70 tiles).

Comment: That's expected. You are limited in bitmap memory to 2-3 times the amount of pixels on screen